# php select row from database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database - named tbl_stats which contains a column (UUID) and a list of user IDs.

Im trying to create a script where http://domain.com/index.php?cid=874365 displays a page with only the values from that user's row.

My current code connects to the database but always shows the information from the top row, regardless of what the ?cid= is.

My current code:

```
<?php
 error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', '[REDACTED]');
    define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '[REDACTED]');
    define('DB_DATABASE', '[REDACTED]');


    $dboptions = array(
                  PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE, 
                  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
                  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                );

    try {
      $DB = new PDO(DB_DRIVER.':host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD , $dboptions);  
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
      die;
    }

    //get error/success messages
    if ($_SESSION["errorType"] != "" && $_SESSION["errorMsg"] != "" ) {
        $ERROR_TYPE = $_SESSION["errorType"];
        $ERROR_MSG = $_SESSION["errorMsg"];
        $_SESSION["errorType"] = "";
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "";
    }

        try {
           $cid = intval($_GET['cid']);
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_stats WHERE 1 AND UUID=$cid";
           $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
           $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $cid);

           $stmt->execute();
           $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
          echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        ?>
```

And then to quote the info on the page, I use the following:

```
<?php echo $results[0]["username"] ?>
```

Comment: You have no placeholders therefore nothing to `bind`

Comment: Your issue is [**intval()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function that you have used with `$_GET['cid']` for some reason it return 1. The reason is `$_GET['cid']` is an array. Why, I don't know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the help guys!

Managed to get this fixed thanks to you!

```
    try {
   $cid = $_GET['cid'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_stats WHERE UUID=:cid";
   $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $cid);

   $stmt->execute();
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You were 90% there. That's got it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the placeholder in the SQL statement

```
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_stats WHERE UUID=:cid";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have changed that line, but now no data is being displayed.